# Difference between array of pointers to char and array of pointers to int

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

This is a C question:

I dont understand why this code works:

```
char *c[] = {"hello","world"};
```

But this doesnt:

```
int *v[] = {{1,2},{3,4}};
```

For me they are the same thing (array of pointers initialized with their respective type) but clearly they are not. What is exaclty the difference then? Thanx.

Edit: If the person who downvoted my post could say WHY this is a bad question... that would be great.

Comment: If this is C/C++ there isn't really a difference. I wouldn't use them interchangeably, but data wise these are the same.

Comment: But hte compiler shows me warnings with the int one, and I cant have access to a single element. v[0]{0] for example, halts the program and does not show anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about C, the differences are:

- `"hello"` defines an array of characters
- arrays can decay to pointers

However:

- `{1,2}` does not define an array of `int`s.  It specifies a list of values which can be used as initializers to fields of type `int` (or convertible).

The analogous case for the `int` would be to use a compound array literal:

```
int *v[] = { (int[]){1,2}, (int[]){3,4} };
```

Compound literals default to being writable (unlike string literals), so you can then go `v[0][0] = 5;`, which you cannot do with the `char` version.

Comment: If {1,2} does not define an array, why v[] = {1,2} works then?

Comment: @Zaratustra because in a declaration, the initial values for an array can be specified by a brace-enclosed list.  (The brace-enclosed list isn't an expression). The `=` sign in a declaration isn't an assignment operator.

Answer (score 2):

While the name of an array does decay into a pointer in some contexts (for example `myArray[5]` is really just another way of saying `*(myArray + 5)`), arrays and pointers are not the same thing in the C language.

One difference is that the contents of arrays can be initialized with curly braces `{ }` in the same line they are declared. This is not true with pointers.

```
int a[] = {1,2,3};  // this is okay
int* p  = {7,8,9};  // this isn't
```

Another difference is that pointer variables can be modified, while the address pointed to by an array name is fixed.

```
char* p = "hello";
char a[] = "hello";

a = a + 2;    // this is fine
a++;          // this is fine too

b = b + 2;    // these will cause the compiler to complain
b++;
```

Despite these differences, it is perfectly legal to assign an array's address to a pointer variable--in fact, this is what you are doing when you pass arrays to functions.

```
int a[] = {234,0,-23,34,3};
int* p = a;                 // this is okay
```

The following line is legal because you are defining an array of character pointers. The array `c[]` can be initialized with curly braces `{ }`. But it is still fine to declare character arrays with pointers if you use quotes `" "`.

```
char *c[] = {"hello","world"};
```

This next line isn't allowed because you declared a pointer variable and are also trying to define its contents with `{ }` as it it were an array.

```
int *v[] = {{1,2},{3,4}};
```

You should use this instead:

```
int v[][2] = {{1,2},{3,4}};
```

Comment: The last line does not compile.

Comment: Whoops. I forgot that the compiler cannot figure out both array dimensions on its own. It should be fine now.

Answer (score 1):

The string "hello" (rather all string declared with quotations [""]) are of type const char* hence the first one succeeds, since it initializes the array with two char pointers .
However {1,2} is not of type (int *) hence it would not be used to initialize an array of int pointers.

Comment: Ok, I got that. But what type is {1,2} then?

Comment: Since pointers are not arrays we cannot use aggregate initializers to fill out the memory. Using int a[2] = {1,2} would work since the array is allocated memory on the stack and curly braces are used to initialize the array however a pointer doesn't behave the same. For reference : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization