# Pointers in C - int array VS char array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I know similar questions have been asked, but this one is specific to arrays.

I can do this:

```
char *names[] = { "John", "Paul", "George", "Ringo" };
```

and then:

```
printf("%s\n", names[0]);
```

So why does this not work?:

```
int *numbers[] = { 11, 12, 13, 14 };

printf("%d\n", numbers[0]);
```

Thanks

Comment: It would if you'd drop that asterisk. It's not there for show, it changes the type of the array elements.

Comment: You don't have a char array, you have an array of pointers to char.

Comment: Also please describe "does this not work"!

Comment: @StoryTeller yeah I'm not completely dumb, I get that the asterix isn't for show. I wanted to understand pointers better and was confused why I can create an array of pointers to chars and not an array of pointers to ints

Answer (score 2):

String literals have types of character arrays. For example the string literal `"John"`  has type `char[5]` (string literals include the terminating zero).

Used in expressions arrays with rare exceptions are converted to pointers to their first elements.

You can imagine this declaration

```
char *names[] = { "John", "Paul", "George", "Ringo" };
```

like

```
char *names[] = { &"John"[0], &"Paul"[0], &"George"[0], &"Ringo"[0] };
```

Thus the array `names` is initialized by valid addresses of first characters of the string literals.

As for this declaration

```
int *numbers[] = { 11, 12, 13, 14 };
```

then the array `numbers` is initialized by invalid addresses values like 11, 12 and so on that do not point to actual objects.

You could write for example

```
int i = 11, j = 12, k = 13, l = 14;
```

and then

```
int *numbers[] = { &i, &j, &k, &l };
```

In this case the array would be initialized by valid addresses.

As for the `printf` calls then the function is designed such a way that when the conversion specifier `s` is encountered the function considers the corresponding argument as an address of a zero-terminating string and tries to output this string.

While the conversion specifier `d` serves to output objects of the type int. So for example if you want to output the integer pointed to by `numbers[0]` then you should write

```
printf("%d\n", *numbers[0] );
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that clears it up for me. So basically, the reason it works with chars is because the strings are actually just arrays, and the C program sees the beginning of those arrays as valid addresses. Whereas when we point at ints, because they are not arrays, the C program sees this as an invalid address. Not sure if my own deduction is spot on but definitely becoming clearer. Thanks!

Comment: @RyanMc Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

`"John"`, … are of type `char *`.

`11`, … are of type `int` (without indirection).

So it is:

```
int numbers[] = { 11, 12, 13, 14 };
printf("%d\n", numbers[0]);
```

Comment: *""John", … are of type char *"* - Not quite

Answer (score -1):

**This question is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28222001/difference-between-array-of-pointers-to-char-and-array-of-pointers-to-int?noredirect=1&lq=1).**

In the first example each name is an array and you have an array of arrays.

```
char *names[] = { "John", "Paul", "George", "Ringo" };
```

In the second example with int you have a simple array and using *var[] = **var but you don't have such ting in memory.

```
int *numbers[] = { 11, 12, 13, 14 };
```

Comment: If it's a duplicate, why re-iterate it? SO doesn't work like this.